# How to check if the date is below 4 years in Angular?

Tags: javascript, angular

How can I check if the date in below than 4 years in Angular (JavaScript)?

I would like to show one message if it's true and another message if false.

I would like to check for specific date for example 08.07.2015 (exactly 4 years from now, to get this date and compare).

My code:

```js
public yearsDif() {
    const field = this.fForm.get("field").value;

    let diff = new Date().getFullYear() - new Date(field).getFullYear();

    if (diff < 4) {
      alert('under 4 years');
    }else{
      alert('more than 4 years');
    }
 }
```

Comment: I still your code is valid. Is there any issue your this approach ?

Comment: I would like to compare the exact 4 years from now(for instance 8.7.2015) To compare with this date and return 4 years.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well there are many ways using through plain JS Date() and using moment.js Better is to use moment.js and use it as below -

```js
var firstDate = moment("2016-12-02", 'YYYY-MM-DD'); 
var secondDate = moment("2016-12-02", 'YYYY-MM-DD');
var duration = moment.duration(secondDate.diff(firstDate));
var years = duration.asYears();

if (years < 4) {
  alert('under 4 years');
}else{
  alert('more than 4 years');
}
```

Answer (score 5):

use moment.js, for an example:

```
var years = moment().diff('1981-01-01', 'years',false);
if (years < 4) {
  alert('under 4 years');
}else{
  alert('more than 4 years');
}
```